# VS2010 load project failed with error framework version=v4.0 not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-7-x64, vssdk

I can't make my VS2010 environment work well after reinstalled VS2010, .Net framework 4.0, .net framework4.5, visual studio 2010 SDK on my Win7 64bit.
The error message is as the first picture below:
[image]
I can't understand the message for I had installed .Net framework 4.0. Does 4.5 will override the firstly installed 4.0? When I tried to run .NET Framework 4.0 installer again, it show me "Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer" and I have no choice but quit.

Those projects are developed under VS2010 and loaded and built well until I reinstalled my tools mentioned above.

My software installed is as the pictures below:
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Windows SDK 2010 ( winsdk_web_2010_SDK.exe) and everything is OK. This may not be a clear answer. However, [this note](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2011/04/01/visual-c-2010-sp1-compiler-update-for-the-windows-sdk-7-1/) may help when you install VS2010. It do help me.

Still I'm not sure whether Windows SDK 2010 and VS SDK 2010 are the same thing.